# bundle install gives error for sufia which is based on project hydra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, bundle

I am trying to clone an app which is running with `Sufia` as a font-end based on `project hydra`.

I have installed all the requirements such as `solr` and `fcrepo_wrapper`.

When I generate a test app and when I am doing bundle install I get [this](http://pastebin.com/8qwDVpwv) error.

I am using `ruby-2.3.0` and `rails-5.0.1`.

Anyone else faced this issue with Project-hydra? Please suggest.